# Terminal multiple countdown timer app for Bash / Zsh

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, zsh, xdotool, time-management

I'm looking for an app to organize my daily tasks in different countdown timers similar to the one found at [www.timeanddate.com/timer/](http://www.timeanddate.com/timer/)

Features I'm looking for would be:

- runs in terminal bash or zsh
- multiple independent countdown timers
- plays a sound or notification display once a timer runs out

Please note that timetracking is not an important feature, just the countdown is enough.

Thank you.

---

[image]

Comment: I know Emacs' org-mode has a countdown-timer feature, but I've never used it and know nothing else about it. It might be something look into, though.

Comment: Of the top of my head I could think of a python script that does timer countdown , perhaps even multiple timers in same script, but . . . starting/stopping/resetting individual ones is a bit difficult. You'd ether have to have dedicated terminal window with multiple tabs or use something like `byobu` multiplexer or "terminator" terminal emulator to have several splits in the same window.

Comment: adding/stopping/resetting individual ones *in theory* can be done with `ncurses` library and in C, but not  in bash

Comment: If your goal is to decrease dependency on the online app and use something local,  I could also think of an indicator for Unity panel that does that. Concurrent/independent items can be done that way.  If you specifically want terminal app, it's very hard to achieve for reasons i stated in previous comments

Comment: @NickWeinberg It looks like the tea timer was planned, but not implemented. Thank you, though. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17796/emacs-tea-time-is-supposed-to-be-integrated-in-org-mode-but-apparently-its-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine tmux or screen with termdown.

Termdown is an ncurses timer.

http://www.slashgeek.net/2016/10/25/termdown-cli-countdown-timer-stopwatch/ shows how termdown works.

tmux and screen allow you to run multiple countdowns at once.

I'd make scripts like

```
~/.bin/pomodoro:
#!/bin/sh
termdown 25:00 && mplayer /path/to/sound.mp3

~/.bin/5minbreak:
#!/bin/sh
termdown 05:00 && mplayer /path/to/break.mp3
```

And, I'll execute `pomodoro` in a tmux or screen window.
That way, I can create multiple countdowns.

Do you want notifications? You can combine notification commands with termdown, too.

I'd set up multiple tmux windows for specific timers in advance.

Comment: Hey there @crocket. Have just found termdown today. If you look at [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049145/409485) I have now updated it to include the running termdown for that functionality. Just a bit more creature comforts for a more pleasant user experience.

Comment: Thank you, just discovered your answer and love the solution!

Answer (score 7):

From terminal use the "at" command to set your timer, "at" is very flexible for it can be used with both absolute and relative time (for more info: `man at`):

```
at now + 1 minute <<<'notify-send ALARM'
```

"notify-send" will place a notification on your desktop
(feel free to replace it with i.e. "aplay" to make a sound instead of a notification).

Comment: Great answer, I like the simplicity. Is there any way to display the time left (like a countdown), too?

Comment: no, not with "at".   if you would like to have a shell-window constantly open to be able to check the countdown time, you're probably better of with a while loop and the sleep command.

Comment: A superuser question https://superuser.com/questions/611538/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-countdown-or-stopwatch-timer-in-a-terminal gives a basic loop `N=100; while [[ $((--N)) >  0 ]]; do  echo  $N    && sleep 1 ; done` many more elaborate answers under that question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bash script here in **Ask Ubuntu** called [multi-timer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039357/a-timer-to-set-up-different-alarms-simultaneosly/1039377#1039377)

## `multi-timer` Progress bar display

[image: peek wash cycle.png]

### Features

- Retains configuration between uses.
- Up to 19 timers run sequentially in a set.
- Progress bar for each timer.
- Set of timers can be run multiple times.
- Progress bar for set.
- Progress bar for all sets.
- Optional prompt to start each timer and/or set.
- Optional pop-up message when each timer and/or set ends.
- Optional alarm when each timer and/or set ends.
- Optional lock screen when each timer OR set OR all sets end.
- Optional interface to Sysmonitor Indicator so Systray shows countdowns.
- Optional close progress bar display when all sets of timers end.

#### Visit the link above for screenshots and bash code.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this solution?

Comment: @somethis I wrote the script. It's been working every Wednesday night for two years. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Runs perfectly and I marked it as a solution to the question. Very nice script, carefully crafted.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a shell function have come up with today to solve this exact problem for myself. I do happen to think that it works rather well. Full usage instructions are included in the comments.

***updated:***

Now requires a new dependancy, `termdown`, for displaying a countdown timer in the terminal.

If you want to use this shell function as a script, then just copy paste it into a new file with the `#!/bin/sh` shebang as line 1. And then at the end of the file call the function as `timer "$@"` to pass all the cmdline arguments into it.

Hopefully that addresses the previously raised criticism.

```
timer() {
  # tested on ubuntu 18.04
  # installation: copy-paste this shell function into your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile

  # program dependencies
  # to install missing dependancies on ubuntu
  #  # sudo apt-get install -y xcowsay
  #  # sudo snap install -y termdown 
  # this shell function also uses `paplay` (for making a beep / ding sound)
  # and `pgrep` for checking when any xcowsay window was clicked on and dismissed
  # (however on ubuntu desktop 18.04, both `paplay` and `pgrep` are already installed by default)

  # usage examples
  # input string is parsed by the unux date command. tested with "date (GNU coreutils) 8.28"
  # ... this version of date seems able to understand and translate these human-readable strings

  # timer "1h1m30s"
  # timer "1h 1m 30s"
  # timer "1 minute 30 seconds"
  # timer "15 minutes"
  # timer "2 hours 30 minutes"

  # timer "00:45:00" # = "45 minutes"
  # timer "00:00:45" # = "45 seconds"
  # timer "1:1:1"    # = 1 hour, 1 minute and 1 second

  # begin
  _time="$1"
  _bell_repeat_delay="3"

  # convert input string to seconds, and sleep until time is up
  # _seconds="$(local epoch=$(date --utc -d @0 +%F); date --utc -d "$epoch $time" +%s.%09N)"



  if echo "$_time" | grep -q -E '^[0-9]+$'; then
      _seconds="$_time"
  else
    _date_flag="$(echo "$_time" | sed  -e "s/s/SECONDS/g"  -e "s/m/MINUTES/g"  -e "s/h/HOURS/g")"
    _seconds="$(date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC ${_date_flag}" "+%s")"
  fi

  _critical="$(echo $_seconds / 10 | bc)"
  if [ $_seconds -lt 60 ]; then
    _critical=20

  elif [ $_seconds -lt 100 ]; then
    _critical=30

  elif [ $_seconds -lt 200 ]; then
    _critical=40

  elif [ $_seconds -lt 300 ]; then
    _critical=60
  fi

  # sleep _seconds && \
  termdown --critical $_critical --voice en $_seconds && \
  (
    # handle ctrl+c gracefully
    trap "killall -q xcowsay; exit 1" INT

    # display notifications on all monitors, 1 notification per monitor
    i=0; num_monitors="$(xrandr -q| grep " connected" | wc -l)"
    while [ "$i" -lt "$num_monitors" ]; do

      # this cmd displays the notification itself, and is further customizable
      xcowsay --monitor=$i --time=0 --cow-size=large "$time is up" &
      i="$(expr $i + 1)"
    done

    _sound_file_timer_expired="/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/drip.ogg"
    _sound_file_remind_repeat="/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga"

    audacious --pause
    # play -v15 "$_sound_file_timer_expired"
    paplay "$_sound_file_timer_expired"

    while true; do
      # detect if any notifications were dismissed, then exit gracefully
      num_cows="$(pgrep -c xcowsay)"
      [ "$(expr $num_monitors - $num_cows)" -gt 0 ] && break
      # make a slowly repeating ding or beep audible alert sound
      paplay "$_sound_file_remind_repeat"
      sleep $_bell_repeat_delay || break
    done

    # dismiss all of the notifications, when displayed on multiple monitors
    killall -q xcowsay
    trap - INT
  )

}
```

Comment: This doesn't need to be a function, so it should be a script. But if you do want to leave it as a function, you should run it in a subshell to prevent affecting the variables in the interactive shell.