# Does Ubuntu 20.04 have an app for multiple timers that allows configuring preset durations?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-panel

Does Ubuntu 20.04 have an app for multiple timers that allows configuring preset durations?

In 18.04 I used one that looked like this:

[image]

It crashed once in a while, but it mostly worked. Now it appears to be gone. Instead we have `gnome-clocks` that does not allow configuring preset durations.

I also found `gnome-shell-pomodoro` and `gnome-shell-timer` but they don't allow multiple timers at all (among other serious problems)

Comment: Is [this timer app](https://computingforgeeks.com/best-countdown-timer-app-for-linux/) of any use as an alternative?

Comment: I wrote one a couple of years ago that might work for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039357/a-timer-to-set-up-different-alarms-simultaneosly